# Specific document for every user

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB and I just can not understand how the database works to the end. For a start, I'll explain what I want to do. It is necessary to make a form on the site through which new users will be added for the client program on WPF.NET in which the connection to the server will occur.

**It is not clear to me where the user should be in the database** in admin or in my database, what is it local, config dbs?

I watched the video and read for the *authentification*. Okay, I created the user, but it connects to the whole database, and so can read the data of another user. I mean that if someone wants to go to the server and hack into or overwrite the data of another client. **Is it possible to give the client access to only a specific document?**

Example:
   **Users**: **ClientUser1**, ClientUser2, ClientUser3
   **Collection ClientCollection**: **Document1ForUser1Only**, Document2ForUser2Only, Document3ForUser3Only

C# WPF .NET Client I Call
new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?db=custom&user=**ClientUser1**&password=1234"
*Access only for **Document1ForUser1Only**, because is it correct user account data.*

**Update1**
It seems to me that all this can be done through roles. I did my part and pointed it to the user. But when I do a search for my collections, it shows me a mistake. And in the program Studio 3T I do not see any collection.

```
db.createRole({ role: "User",
  privileges: [
    { resource: { db: "testdb", collection: "UserCollection" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove" ]}
  ],
  roles: []
})

> show collections  
2018-05-13T20:38:09.463+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listCollections failed:   {  
        "ok" : 0,  
        "errmsg" : "not authorized on testdb to execute command {  
 listCollections: 1.0, filter: {}, $db: \"testdb\" }",  
        "code" : 13,
        "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13  
DB.prototype._getCollectionInfosCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:941:1  
DB.prototype.getCollectionInfos@src/mongo/shell/db.js:953:19  
DB.prototype.getCollectionNames@src/mongo/shell/db.js:964:16  
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:813:9  
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:710:15  
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

Comment: Y this is possible.Like this:user.find({},'-password'....  this mean is yoy can get all users's data;but you cant get user's password.

Comment: Because you dont write your code.I can only give you a proposal.

Comment: It would probably be a clearer question if you could actually demonstrate what you are asking. As it stands the "words" where you admit you don't really understand the topic are not really explaining what you mean. If not code, then something else that at least illustrates the question, which I must agree is not really that clear as to what you intend or what the specific problem may be

Comment: Being new to the site it is advisable that you take the time to read [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and particularly the section on "Help others Reproduce the Problem", as questions which provide this tend to get useful answers and of course give you the solution you are looking for.